# Pyspark Dataframe Null value Logic Operation

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In python, None !=1 will return True.
But why in Pyspark "Null_column" != 1 will return false?
example:

```
data = [(1,5),(2,5)]
columns=["id","test"]
df_null=spark.createDataFrame(data,columns)
df_null = df_null.withColumn("nul_val",lit(None))
df_null.printSchema()
df_null.show()
```

[image]

but `df_null.filter(df_null.nul_val != 1).count()` will return 0

Answer (score 0):

Please check [NULL Semantics - Spark 3.0.0](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0-preview/sql-ref-null-semantics.html) for how to handle comparison with `null` in spark.

But to summerize, in Spark, null is undefined , so any comparison with null will result in undefined and should be avoided to avoid unwanted results. And in your case, since undefined is not True, the count will be 0.

> Apache spark supports the standard comparison operators such as ‘>’, ‘>=’, ‘=’, ‘<’ and ‘<=’. The result of these operators is unknown or NULL when one of the operarands or both the operands are unknown or NULL.

If you want to compare with a column that might contain null, use the null-safe operation `<=>` which results in `False` if one of the operands is null:

> In order to compare the NULL values for equality, Spark provides a null-safe equal operator (‘<=>’), which returns False when one of the operand is NULL

So, back to your problem. To solve it I would do a null-check and the comparison with 1:

```
df_null.filter((df_null.nul_val.isNull()) | (df_null.nul_val != 1)).count()
```

Another solution would be to replace null with 0, if that does not destroy any other logic:

```
df_null.fill(value=0,subset=["nul_val"]).filter(df_null.nul_val != 1).count()
```